# How to edit the WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: fckeditor

What is the best way to add a custom WYSIWYG to custom objects?

So instead of this
[image: Image 1]

We want to see this:
[image: Image 2]

Comment: maybe the answer to this question will answer yours  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57711/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-wysiwyg-editor-for-sending-emails

Comment: You need to use ckeditor and write custom code to get the data and save it to Salesforce. With Salesforce Classic it is possible to do some customization on that out of the box editor but it will be lots of work in lightning it will be more challenging.

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/features